# Putting button outside form but in the same line of submit button

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to put a button in the in the same line of a form.

```
<form name="search_form" method="get" action="results1.php">
Organism <select name="organism_list" size="1" id="organism_list" >
      <option selected="selected">All</option>
      <option id="human" name="organism_human">Human </option>
      <option id="mouse" name="organism_mouse">Mouse </option>
      <option id="rat"  name="organism_rat">Rat </option>
</select>        
Query <input name="query_textbox" type="text" id="textbox1" value="" />
<input name="search_button" type="submit" id="search_button" value="Go" />
</form>
<input name="ad_search_button" type="submit" id="ad_search_button" value="Advance Search" />
```

I want the ad_search_button to be adjacent to search_button. But due to the form it is not being placed at my desired position. What should I do?

Comment: What is supposed to happen if you click on the Advanced Search button?

Comment: Two submit buttons for one for? What's the purpose?

Comment: Marc Audet     Sir, I want to redirect the user to a different page named ad_search.php using this button.

Comment: BTW - "Advance" is a verb. "Advanced" is an adjective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you cannot keep your input button ad_search_button inside the form, then you can make it `position:absolute` and adjust its top, right, left , bottom properties to come in line with the `search_button`.

Otherwise, these are the only two possibilities you got.

- make your entire form `float:left`, which will cause the 'ad_search_button' to come to the right of it. Also in this case, width of the entire form should be less than the total width of the screen, so that `ad_search_button` can be accomodated.
- or you can simply keep your `ad_search_button` inside the form. it should get rendered to the left of `search_button`
- [ad_search_button kept inside](http://jsfiddle.net/manishmishra256/WYC4D/)
- [ad_search_button kept outside](http://jsfiddle.net/manishmishra256/WYC4D/1/)

Comment: Yuck!  Absolute positioning almost always comes back to bite me later.  Especially when everything else is done properly.

Comment: thn, you have to move your ad_search_button inside the form and make search_button float left :)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest changing that button to an anchor tag and then placing it inside the form, it will have no affect on the form then.

This is assuming that the advanced search doesnt have to be inside its own form (which in your example it is not)

e.g.

```
    <input name="search_button" type="submit" id="search_button" value="Go" />
    <a href="/ad_search.php">Advanced Search</a>
</form>
```

Keep it simple.

Answer (score 0):

You could just put the whole thing in a table:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><form>...</form></td>
    <td>other button here</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/V273j/

Answer (score 0):

Put the buttons in a `div` inside the form, then add some css styling.

http://jsfiddle.net/25u4c/1/

Comment: Try again, it has been fixed to work in chrome & ff.  Your method is fine, I just prefer divs to table.